# CPU time on process which different no of threads

Tags: multithreading, process, operating-system, scheduling

If a process have more no of thread i say 100 and other process have less no of threads
i say only 2 so both will get equal time or a process with more no of threads gets more 
time

Comment: *most* operating systems have a concept of priority, which you've not mentioned at all, and has far more bearing on share of CPU. But the answer will also probably depend on the *specific* scheduling mechanics of the operating system. You could write your own OS that performs any scheduling process that you want it to.

Comment: @PeterHorvath: please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253780/is-it-ok-to-downvote-questions-because-of-bad-grammar. You have enough reputation to fix it if it bothers you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how much processing time they need. So long as sufficient resources are available, the scheduler will give each thing it schedules however much CPU time it requires.

It's a common misconception that it's somehow "fairer" to give each process equal CPU time. For one thing, that unfairly rewards creating large numbers of processes. It's no more inherently fair to treat every process equally than it is to treat every thread equally.